# iOS/Objective-C "if" best practice

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've got this code that I found in a project and I'm wondering how can it be done better:

```
- (void) setAlpha:(float)alpha {
    if (self.superview.tag == noDisableVerticalScrollTag) {
        if (alpha == 0 && self.autoresizingMask == UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin) {
            if (self.frame.size.width < 10 && self.frame.size.height > self.frame.size.width) {
                UIScrollView *sc = (UIScrollView*)self.superview;
                if (sc.frame.size.height < sc.contentSize.height) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (self.superview.tag == noDisableHorizontalScrollTag) {
        if (alpha == 0 && self.autoresizingMask == UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin) {
            if (self.frame.size.height < 10 && self.frame.size.height < self.frame.size.width) {
                UIScrollView *sc = (UIScrollView*)self.superview;
                if (sc.frame.size.width < sc.contentSize.width) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [super setAlpha:alpha];
}
```

Comment: Woah there. That's a big set of conditions. It would be more helpful to know context: what do these do, why are they here, and what do they apply to? It may be possible to break this up into different components by using more OOP functionality, but without that, it's hard to help.

Comment: This code appears to have been taken from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8607393/1157100) without attribution — which also makes this question off-topic.

Comment: @200_success, this code was taken from an actual project I was working on at that time and that made me" wtf" when I saw it. But I'm glad you're taking interest in a question asked 3 years ago. Hope you get your points. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, using the `tag` to distinguish between views is almost everytime (there are exceptions) a bad idea. It's much cleaner to use your own variable (pointers to view, `BOOL` flags).

`10` is a magic number. What does it mean? Use a constant.

Use methods. Four levels of `if` are terrible. Extract the code into methods.

```
if ([self isVerticalScrollingDisabled] || [self isHorizontalScrollingDisabled]) {
    return;
}

[super setAlpha:alpha];
```

By the way, changing the behavior of a method in a subclass (the method sets alpha only if some conditions are valid) is smelly from architecture point of view. Declaring a special method, e.g. `setAlphaIfScrollingEnabled:` would be better.

Comment: Exactly, it violates LSP

Comment: +1.  For example, they could use KVO to listen for alpha changes, and perform the *side effects* then, instead of overriding `setAlpha:`.

Answer (score 0):

That’s almost unreadable. Or, more precisely, it’s plain what the code does, but it’s almost impossible to guess the purpose. Generally, there are two conditions that prevent the view from taking a new alpha setting, right? Some general remarks:

- The `noDisableHorizontalScrollTag` constant deserves a better name. It’s a good idea to mark constants with uppercase initial letter (think `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`, `CGRectZero` and similar), but more importantly the double negation (*no disable*) is needlessly hard to parse. Why not `EnableHorizontalScrollingTag`? Or something similar, better fitting your use case.
- If possible, it’s good to avoid changing view behaviour according to its superview. Especially when you assume here that the superview is always a `UIScrollView`. Maybe you could introduce some “delegate” or “data source” style pointer to the view to read the constraints from? That would also express the type constraint in the type system, making it possible for the compiler to check the code for you. Again, hard to say more without understanding your use case.

But above all, you should introduce some higher-level concept to make the code readable. Like wrap the frame-checking logic into a named method, where the name would be some meaningful concept (`isVerticalScrollingEnabled`, for example). Otherwise it’s very hard to find the connection between alpha, autoresizing mask, superview’s frame and its content size.

But maybe we’re just missing context here.